# cups restarted automatically

Tags: linux, centos, printing, cups

I have installed a cups service on a CentOS 7.1 64 bits.

We have some problems with a printer and the only thing I can see on logs is /var/log/messages:

```
May 18 12:11:37 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
May 18 12:11:44 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
May 18 12:11:44 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
May 18 12:18:37 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
May 18 12:18:37 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
May 18 12:18:38 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
May 18 12:18:38 isis systemd: Started CUPS Printing Service.
```

I do not understand how cups is restarted automatically. Is this behavior normal? It could be affecting printings

Could you help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: `cupsd` might be crashing, or who knows. Find the logs or increase the log level for `cupsd`, find out how systemd is starting it and then try starting it manually in the foreground, etc.